# Django multi-image upload in admin panel with ajax - some example

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-admin

I find many articles with multi-image and plugins:

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiuploader etc.

But I don't know how use it in django admin when I have ImageField. I want to do gallery.

Now I have inline adding image in albums. Please help me and give some full example :) (I'm newbie)

Answer (score 0):

We use django-jfu to upload many files outside the admin.

Interfacing to the admin is certainly possible by creating a custom admin method to invoke jfu.  Add a completion button to the jfu upload page that creates the desired db records when the user is done uploading files.  These would then be available within the admin.

Comment: Please give me some example. I ready don't know how use it :/

Comment: Django JFU is reasonably well documented here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jfu/2.0.1 and here https://github.com/blueimp/jquery-file-upload.  The details of its use depend on your application particulars.  If you work through the demo it should be apparent how to use it in your application.